# Android : Spinner throws IndexOutOfBoundsException after adapter setting

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner, indexoutofboundsexception

Seems very primitive problem, but..

I have method, where I create and set an custom adapter :

```
public void fillCountryAdapter()
    {
        Log.i(TAG + "fillCountryAdapter","");
        ArrayList<CountryInfo> countriesList  = new ArrayList<CountryInfo>();
                        countriesList.add(new CountryInfo("afghanistan", "AF ", "93", R.drawable.ad));
                        countriesList.add(new CountryInfo("albania", "AL ", "355",R.drawable.af));
                         countriesList.add(new CountryInfo("algeria", "DZ ", "213",R.drawable.dz));


        CountryAdapter countriesArrayAdapter = new CountryAdapter(getActivity(),
                 android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,countriesList);
        countriesArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.country_item);

        registerCodePhone.setAdapter(countriesArrayAdapter);
}
```

Everything done in fragment. In the onCreateView I call this mehod. And in the

```
registerCodePhone
                .setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                            int arg2, long arg3) {
                        Log.i("choosed item", Integer.toString(registerCodePhone.getAdapter().getCount()));
                        Log.i("choosed item", ((CountryInfo)registerCodePhone.getAdapter().getItem(arg2)).toString() );

                    }

                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                        Log.i("un choosed item", registerCodePhone
                                .getSelectedItem().toString());

                    }

                });
```

`registerCodePhone.getAdapter().getItem(arg2)` and a `registerCodePhone.getSelectedItem().toString()` throws :

```
02-10 15:29:24.498: E/AndroidRuntime(24725): Process: com.assignmentexpert, PID: 24725
02-10 15:29:24.498: E/AndroidRuntime(24725): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
02-10 15:29:24.498: E/AndroidRuntime(24725):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
02-10 15:29:24.498: E/AndroidRuntime(24725):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
02-10 15:29:24.498: E/AndroidRuntime(24725):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getItem(ArrayAdapter.java:337)
02-10 15:29:24.498: E/AndroidRuntime(24725):    at com.fragments.RegisterFragment$10.onItemSelected(RegisterFragment.java:202)
02-10 15:29:24.498: E/AndroidRuntime(24725):    at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:893)
02-10 15:29:24.498: E/AndroidRuntime(24725):    at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:48)
02-10 15:29:24.498: E/AndroidRuntime(24725):    at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:861)
02-10 15:29:24.498: E/AndroidRuntime(24725):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
02-10 15:29:24.498: E/AndroidRuntime(24725):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-10 15:29:24.498: E/AndroidRuntime(24725):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-10 15:29:24.498: E/AndroidRuntime(24725):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-10 15:29:24.498: E/AndroidRuntime(24725):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-10 15:29:24.498: E/AndroidRuntime(24725):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-10 15:29:24.498: E/AndroidRuntime(24725):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-10 15:29:24.498: E/AndroidRuntime(24725):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-10 15:29:24.498: E/AndroidRuntime(24725):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

`toString()` is overrided in my CountryInfo class. Interesting, that the count of adapter of this Spinner before `getSelectedItem()` is not null.

What can cause this ?

Comment: What line is RegisterFragment.java:202

Comment: this one : Log.i("choosed item", ((CountryInfo)registerCodePhone.getAdapter().getItem(arg2)).toString() );

Comment: Is your spinner being populated with the `countriesArrayAdapter`? Maybe print out the spinner list or put a break point on the `registerCodePhone.setAdapter(countriesArrayAdapter);` line